# How to mapply a function with multiple variables across multiple lists

Tags: r, mapply

I'm a little out of my depth with mapply() and do.call...

So I have two lists like so:

```
ID          START           END
a1        1/1/2000       1/30/2000
a2        5/4/2000       3/1/2002
a3        5/8/2004       8/7/2005
a4        1/3/2012       5/7/2015


ID          START           END
b1        5/1/2000       1/30/2020
b2        6/4/2007       3/1/2008
b3        5/8/2014       8/7/2015
b4        1/3/1999       5/7/2019
```

Many of the dates overlap with each other, and that's what I'm trying to identify.  I'm trying to create a column for each entry on the second list onto the first that says whether or not the date ranges overlap...

```
ID          START           END        b1      b2      b3     b4
a1        1/1/2000       1/30/2000      0       0       0      1
a2        5/4/2000       3/1/2002       1       0       0      1
a3        5/8/2004       8/7/2005       1       0       0      1
a4        1/3/2012       5/7/2015       1       0       1      1
```

where a 0 represents un-overlapping events, and 1 represents overlap.

My effort so far has been to use dplyr mutate in a function with multiple variables.  Then I'm trying to use mapply to feed the whole lists in as those variables...

```
builder <- function(id,start,finish){
      resource_const_all <- resource_const %>% 
      mutate(id = ifelse(start > START & start < END,"1",
                  ifelse(finish > START & finish < END, "1",
                  ifelse(start < START & finish > END, "1", "0"))))
      }  
###if the start date falls in the date range, it returns 1.
###if the end date falls in the date range, it returns 1.
###if the start date is before the date range and the end date is after, it 
###returns 1.
###Else the dates don't overlap, returns 0.


builder_output <- mapply(builder,id_list,start_list,end_list))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Far from my box at the moment, but take a look at `data.table::foverlaps`

Comment: @PavoDive -- This is very helpful, I think I'll be making use of this in my current script.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end where we ensure that the `START` and `END` columns are of `Date` class. Then use `outer` as shown.

Note that `overlap` is a generic test and `overlapAB` makes it specific to `A` and `B`.

No packages are used.

```
overlap <- function(start1, end1, start2, end2) {
  (start1 >= start2 & start1 <= end2) |  (start2 >= start1 & start2 <= end1)
}

overlapAB <- function(idA, idB) {
  i <- match(idA, A$ID)
  j <- match(idB, B$ID)
  overlap(A$START[i], A$END[i], B$START[j], B$END[j])
}

cbind(A, +outer(A$ID, B$ID, overlapAB))
```

giving:

```
  ID      START        END b1 b2 b3 b4
1 a1 2000-01-01 2000-01-30  0  0  0  1
2 a2 2000-05-04 2002-03-01  1  0  0  1
3 a3 2004-05-08 2005-08-07  1  0  0  1
4 a4 2012-01-03 2015-05-07  1  0  1  1
```

### Note

```
LinesA <- "ID          START           END
a1        1/1/2000       1/30/2000
a2        5/4/2000       3/1/2002
a3        5/8/2004       8/7/2005
a4        1/3/2012       5/7/2015"

LinesB <- "ID          START           END
b1        5/1/2000       1/30/2020
b2        6/4/2007       3/1/2008
b3        5/8/2014       8/7/2015
b4        1/3/1999       5/7/2019"

fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
A <- read.table(text = LinesA, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
A$START <- as.Date(A$START, fmt)
A$END <- as.Date(A$END, fmt)

B <- read.table(text = LinesB, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
B$START <- as.Date(B$START, fmt)
B$END <- as.Date(B$END, fmt)
```